# Screensaver in Elementary OS - how to disable it?

Tags: display, battery

I cannot find any information about disabling screensaver in Elementary OS. It is possible that it is connected to another app installed on my computer?

Best regards,
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found working solution. Here it is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 3600
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false

killall gnome-screensaver ; xset dpms force on
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually installed a screensaver or do you mean when the screen goes to black? If so you'll go to ***System Settings*** ==> ***Power***.
Under ***Turn off display when inactive*** set it to ***Never***.
You can also do it with Suspend set it to ***Never***

regards

Comment: I does not work :/

Comment: I guess it's the latest version of eOS you're using and somehow it don't play well with your hardware as it works on my Desktop and laptop. You may check for bug report and see if someone with similar problems.

Comment: yes i got it. I pasted solution below. Probably it is a problem with Elementary OS and kernel.